# Selenium reactjs enable javascript issue

Tags: selenium

I am using **selenium** with **nodejs** to test a **react** web app. I am able to do login and inspect required element. There is a dropdown and when i select a option the page goes blank. I checked the page source, i see this -

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

When manually doing same it works fine.

Following is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className('react-select__value-container')).click().then(function () {
  driver.findElements(By.className('react-select__option')).then(function (elems) {
    if (elems.length) {
      elems.map(function (el) {
        el.getText().then(function (txt) {
          console.log('txt = ', txt)
          if (city == txt) {
            el.click();
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, how you inspecting element through script? Add your code trials as well.

Comment: i have updated question with my code as well. plz check.Thanks.